# Why RST instructions are called one byte call instruction in 8085

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

Why **RST** instructions are called one byte call instruction in 8085 ?

Comment: How would you describe, in your own words, what an RST instruction does?  How many bytes does one take to encode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular 8085 "CALL" instruction must fetch the 16-bit **subroutine address**, so that makes it a 3-byte instruction (one for the 0xCD instruction fetch, two more for the following subroutine address).

The "RST" instruction doesn't have to fetch an address, so that makes it a one-byte instruction (just the instruction fetch). A snippet of the address is contained in the instruction itself, comprising three of the eight bits. The call address becomes (in binary) `00000000 00xxx000`, where `xxx` are the three bits found inside the RST instruction fetched:( `11xxx111` ). The call addresses formed are on the first page of the 64K address space.

*Similar* to a call, the RST instruction must push a 16-bit **return address** onto the stack: one instruction fetch cycle, and two more memory-write cycles to store the return address.

Because RST doesn't have to fetch the **subroutine address**, it runs faster than a CALL. Some 8085's take 18 clock cycles to complete a 3-byte CALL, while a 1-byte RST completes in 12 clock cycles.